# What is the difference between the two sentence in meaning?

Tags: grammar

1. It is easy for you to solve this problem.
2. It is easy that you solve this problem.

What is the difference between the above sentence in meaning?
Please, Let me know the difference you feel.

Comment: 1) is English; 2) is not.

Comment: The first one is English.  The second one is something else.

Answer (score 1):

> It is easy for you to solve this problem.

This indicates that you can solve the problem without difficulties - however, this does not mean that the problem itself is easy.

> It is easy that you solve this problem.

This doesn't make much sense to me. You could possibly change it to `You solved this problem! So it must be easy!` indicating that now you've seen someone solving the problem, you think it must be easy to solve.

Comment: "It's a problem that's easy for you to solve" is how I might reword it.

Comment: Sure, but the thing is - I wanted to avoid `for you` since it is the crucial part the author asked about, so I wanted to use other words when explaining the meaning of this sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The first means the problem is easy. So you can solve it easily.

The second isn't a sentence, so it has no meaning.